# Need to set modifier value in Expresso Store to 0

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I have modifiers for women's clothing sizes set up and am trying to add the size zero. However, when I enter "0" store thinks that the row is empty and doesn't capture it. Could you add support for "0"? Thanks

Comment: Something we had not thought of - will look at fixing this in the next version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not set it as zero in store and then run a simple conditional in the template to check for 'zero' and replace that value with 0 (number)?

Comment: Sure, that would work. What I ended up doing was adding the sizes as "00, 02, 04, etc." which worked fine.